# What is the command line syntax of ClockworkMod recovery?

Tags: adb, backup, clockworkmod-recovery

Background: I recently broke my phone's touch screen; everything else is working - I can even send inputs using `adb shell sendevent ...` and view the screen with `screencap`. ADB while in recovery works as well.

however, since the recovery doesn't have the screencap utility, I can't really do anything in recovery mode. I have found the `recovery` utility, though.

The recovery command though has no help as far as I can tell; there is no man, and neither `recovery -h` nor `recovery --help` show anything. Unsettlingly, the command doesn't even terminate immediately.

Are there any resources on this utility, especially on how I can do a full system backup like I would using the options on the screen?

Comment: You can use twrp instead, it provides command line.